# Fetching data from view to controller in cake php

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp-3.0

I'm having some data to my view page. (stored in the table with the associated data for the result of search) .

The problem is to fetch the `codeID`. I want to send the data from the view to the controller. How can i do that?

Comment: use ajax to send your data to controller

Comment: I don't have any Experience for Ajax :(

Comment: then read it here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ or use html `form`

Comment: Fix the grammatical mistakes and the problem description.